# Improving performance with a common low-cardinality field

Tags: postgresql, join, partitioning

I have a database with multiple tables. Every table has a field named `sourcename`, which indicates basically which customer the data came from. There are only about ten possible values for this field across the entire database, repeated across 300 million rows or more on a given table.

Data from one table row will never join a row on another table with a different `sourcename`. So, it seems obvious to me that I need to figure out how to configure the database so that queries take advantage of this fact. But I don't know how to set it up.

I would think this is some kind of partitioning, but IIUC, partitioning doesn't expressly forbid queries in other partitions. If partitioning or sharding is the way to go, how do I ensure that joined queries don't cross partition boundaries?

I could also literally create different tables, like `sourcename1_entity1`, `sourcename2_entity1`, `sourcename1_entity2`, etc. This would probably work, but it seems messy and doesn't feel right. I guess I'd have to automate creating the tables, and then use a lot of manual `UNION ALL` to get the final result of a given query.

What's the best and simplest way to prevent queries from wasting time looking up values with impossible sourcenames, and if it's a kind of partitioning, what terminology should I use to distinguish it from other kinds of partitioning?

Comment: You could try to create ten filtered indexes e.g. `create index on ... (primary_key_column) where sourcename = 'customer_one';`

Comment: Could you give an example of a query which needs to be faster, along with a query plan for it?

Comment: You might want to look at row level security. This can allow the necessary predicate against `sourcename` to be added for you automatically. This plus partitioning (with appropriate indexing) should be what you want.